# android stringbuilder editTexts

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I have lots of editText fields and the user can add info into them.

from these editTexts i want to create one string. im using the stringBuilder at the moment. however if the user does not enter anything to some of the editTexts, i want the stringbuilder to ignore these fields. is this possible? and if so, how can i do it?

this is what im doing at the moment:

```
String baseString = editText1.getText().toString();
    String string2= editText2.getText().toString();
    String string3= editText3.getText().toString();

 StringBuilder superStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(baseString);
    superStringBuilder.append(string2 + string3);

    String superString = superStringBuilder.toString();
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
If (string2.equals("")){
    //Then do something when the edit text is blank.
    superStringBuilder.append(string3);

} else{
    superStringBuilder.append(string2 + string3);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, i have tried that. However i cant figure out how to remove the string2 from superStringBuilder.append(string2 + string3) if string2 is blank :) hard to explain. hopefuly you understand hehe. (i just saw your edit, il try that :)

Comment: look at my edit, I don't know if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: almost =) the thing is that with lots of editTexts there is lots of diferent combinations. Perhaps there is no way to work around that hehe thank you =)

Comment: i got it working the way i wanted thanks to your help and a bit of altering the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your help this is an example for others if they have the same problem.

```
        String string1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String string2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    String string3 = editText3.getText().toString();
    String string4 = editText4.getText().toString();
    String string5 = editText5.getText().toString();

    StringBuilder superStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string1);

    if (string2.equals("")){
        superStringBuilder.append(""); 
    }else { superStringBuilder.append(string2);
    }

    if (string3.equals("")){
        superStringBuilder.append(""); 
    }else { superStringBuilder.append(string3);
    }

    if (string4.equals("")){
        superStringBuilder.append(""); 
    }else { superStringBuilder.append(string4);
    }

    if (string5.equals("")){
        superStringBuilder.append(""); 
    }else { superStringBuilder.append(string5);
    }

    String superString = superStringBuilder.toString();
```

this will make the string filter out the editText with no text in them :) so the new string created with stringbuilder is either 4 strings or 2 strings :)

thank you